# API Gateway timeout on HTTP Rest API Request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway-v2

I have deployed my legacy application which has few HTTP Rest API's which responds in 1 minute (or greater). As of now there is no way to change this REST application performance.

In front I have API gateway which timeout in 30 seconds and there is no way to increase the 30 seconds timeout and we are facing 504 gateway timeout for Rest API's which is taking more than 30 seconds to respond.

So Other than modifying the REST application, Is there a way to make the change in the AWS side to fix the gateway timeout issue ?

Anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact AWS Support for quota/limit changes, however, I'm quite certain the 29 seconds is a hard limit that cannot be altered. You won't be able to use api gateway unless your APIs respond under 29seconds.